# Where (under what name) can I find these breakable female pin headers?

Tags: components, identification

I'm looking for these pin headers:

[image: pin header]

They're easier to work with than the regular pin headers because of the grooves. 
There are similar headers that are also breakable but with round sockets (I'm not looking for these).

So I'm looking for a name or a search term so that I can find these on typical stores (e.g. aliexpress).

Comment: You can try "Break away female headers".

Comment: @NickAlexeev: Why was Spehro's answer converted to a comment? It was brief and too the point. He's not seeking clarification on the question.

Comment: Yeah he's definitely correct.  These are great, but I'd like to know what the correct way to break these is.  I thought they were shattering because they're 20 years old, but this one looks just the same.

Comment: @KH I was never able to break these neatly along the grooves. Usually I sacrifice one pin to break exactly as on the photo in the question, then use the groove strictly as a guideline when filing jagged edge down.

Comment: can you post a picture of the broken end? ... it is unclear what the exposed contact looks like

Comment: I never saw any that you could break away, all I know have to be cut carefully

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Single row PCB socket header, breakable, through-hole, straight](https://www.digikey.com/short/9zrnd8ct), on Digikey. More than 100 options.

They don't have a machined pin (round), just like you asked.

Comment: Wow, after three years...!

Answer (score 3):

I know it's been a long time since you asked this, but I was looking for the same thing and found those [BL 1 36 Z](https://www.arrow.com/en/products/bl136z/fischer-elektronik), which are available in many electronics hardware stores. There are different lengths and are available in gold plated version too. No luck on aliexpress for this one.